# How to convert DateTime of jodatime into LocalDateTime of java

Tags: java, jodatime, localdate

I tried this:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

But it gives compile time error:

```
The method ofInstant(java.time.Instant, java.time.ZoneId) in the type LocalDateTime is not applicable for the arguments (org.joda.time.Instant, java.time.ZoneId)
```

Comment: Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startDateTime.getMillis()), ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```